# SAS - Exporting same dataset to multiple excel files

Tags: sas

I would like to export the dataset to multiple excel files based on a certain variable:

```
proc sql;
    create table try as
    select distinct make from sashelp.cars;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table try2 as
    select count(make) as aaa from sashelp.cars;
quit;

data _null_;
    set try;
    by make;
    call symputx ('make',compress(make,' .'),'g');
run;

data _null_;
    set try2;
    call symputx('n',aaa);
run;

%macro a;
    %do i=1 %to &n;
        %let var= %scan(&make,&i,"@");
        proc export data=testing (where=(make="&make."))
                outfile="C:\Users\&make..xlsx"
                dbms=xlsx replace;
            sheet="&make." ;
        run;
    %end;
%mend ;
%a;
```

My goal is to get all the 38 excel files with the maker name as the filename.

However, all I am able to get here is the last maker name's file.

Would you please point out where I am missing out here? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is that you count the number of cars that have a make, while you should count the **distinct** makes of cars. Now let me also take the opportunity to explain you the into clause of sql, so you don't need that data step anymore

```
proc sql;
    select count(distinct make) 
    into :make_count
    from sashelp.cars;
quit;
```

You remove blanks and point from your make names, but you better remove all non-alphabetic characters at once, with `compress(make, '', 'ka')`, in which the options `k` stands for keep and `a` stands for alphabetic.

Your main error is that you think you append all make names in the macro variable `make`, but **you actually overwrite `make` time and again**: first you write "Cadillac" to it, then "Chevrolet" and by the time you ever use it, it became "Volvo". 
I could explain you how to correct your datastep, but instead, I will learn you an option of that into statement:

```
proc sql;
    select distinct compress(make, '', 'ka')` 
    into :make_list separated by ' '
    from sashelp.cars;
quit;
```

The rest is easy.

```
%macro export_by_make;
    %do make_nr=1 %to &make_count;
        %let make= %scan(&make_list, &make_nr);
        proc export data=sashelp.cars (where=(compress(make, '', 'ka')`="&make."))
                outfile="C:\Users\&make..xlsx"
                dbms=xlsx replace;
            sheet="&make." ;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
%export_by_make;
```

Note that you don't need to specify a separator for the `%scan` function, as we separated by blanks, but anyway, if you do, as you use the macro version of scan, you don't need the quotes around it.

Comment: The reason why you could get away with using the default delimiters for %SCAN() is the combination of using one of the default delimiters (blank) and also eliminating any occurrence of the other default delimiter, `! $ % & ( ) * + , - . / ; < ^¦`, by the use of the compress() function when generating the list into the macro variable.